# Custom Inventory “Stock Out” Allowing Negative Stock

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a stock control system. I've got almost everything in place (with the help of google search) but one last part that I'm trying to implement is eluding me. My 'Stock Out' tab, I would like to be able to reject the input of new stock out if the corresponding part stock (in either the connectors or electronics stock tab) is 0 (seeing as I can't have negative stock). No matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to work. If someone could give me some pointers, that would be amazing! It's been nearly a week trying to solve this and I'm losing the will lol.

I'm very new to using sheets for such systems so please forgive my ignorance if this is fairly easy to do! Here's the link to the sheet I'm working on. This is a copy with less part information but the formulas are the same. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MoZpcOFhACmKy_FsS9T43JEryAFswgheO5a5qtWnRcI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Include enough info in question to allow answering.  Links should complement the question not be required reading.  If having trouble with a formula,  include in question with a description of problem.  **!** Linked spreadsheet needs public share permissions **!** If you want to share a sheet anonymously use [Blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform).  See [How to share a demo spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383) for more info.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a put down! It’s far easier to share the sheet so that it can be edited to test a formula rather than people guessing and a potential answer not working. As I also said, I don’t know what formula to use, hence why none is included. Also, I’m new to sheets and don’t know how to include public share permissions. But thanks for trying to help 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options:

You may use this formula:

```
=IF(B2="",FALSE,D2<=FILTER({'Connector Stock'!F:F;'Electronics Stock'!F:F},{'Connector Stock'!A:A;'Electronics Stock'!A:A}=B2))
```

It compares the value with the current stock. The issue with this is that it will correctly check the stock when you enter the value and not allow incorrect input but it will also "flag" previous entries when later stocks are less than those values:

[image]

What you can do is add a helper column (F in my case) with checkboxes. That checkbox would stablish that when data was entered stock was confirmed (via this previous data validation) and will then not be flagged:

```
=IF(F2=TRUE,TRUE,IF(B2="",FALSE,D2<=FILTER({'Connector Stock'!F:F;'Electronics Stock'!F:F},{'Connector Stock'!A:A;'Electronics Stock'!A:A}=B2)))
```

Try it and let me know! In both cases you won't be able to enter data if B column is blank (which wouldn't allow to check stock if no product is entered)

[image]

Comment: That is PERFCECT!! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer with such detail! Both options work amazingly. Thanks Again!!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! One final note: if you need to modify a value in D column, first delete it and then write the new value in order to "update" the stock and do the verification